# Select data using condition from AVG expression in HR table

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to learn mysql oracle database, I want to show average salary from table employee group by department_id and where average salary is like '%0'. 
here is my query

```
select department_id, AVG(salary) as "Pay Salary per dept" 
from employees 
where department_id is not null and AVG(salary) like '%0'
group by department_id order by department_id
```

what's right query to replace

```
AVG(salary) like '%0' ?
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle.  Please tag the question appropriately.  Also, your question is simple invalid:  it does not make sense to use `like` on numbers, especially non-integers.

Comment: using oracle, can you give some example to answer it? `like` for integer from my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MOD` function instead of `LIKE`.

```
where MOD(salary,10)=0
```

**query**

```
select t.dept_id,t.Pay_Salary_per_dept
from
(
   select dept_id, AVG(salary) as Pay_Salary_per_dept
   from employee 
   where dept_id is not null
   group by dept_id
)t
where mod(t.Pay_Salary_per_dept,10)=0
order by t.dept_id;
```

[Fiddle demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5717f/1)

Comment: @FatchulAmin: Please check my updated answer and fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To filter the result of aggregated functions there is the HAVING clause in SQL.
You may write it direct without a subquery as follows:

```
select dept_id, AVG(salary) as Pay_Salary_per_dept
from employee 
where dept_id is not null
group by dept_id
having mod(AVG(salary),10)=0
;
```